# Opposite of Candid Photograph?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

What’s the opposite of a *candid photo*?

- staged photo
- posed photo

Neither *staged photo* nor *posed photo* sounds right though.

Comment: Why don't they sound right?

Comment: [Studio photography](http://photo.net/learn/studio/primer)?

Comment: I'm puzzled at your apparent unwillingness, on returning to the EL&U site after first posting your question, to clarify your statement that neither 'staged photo' nor 'posed photo' sounds right. The impression created is that your question was based on a frivolous whim.

Comment: Sorry, Erik, it's not unwillingness just didn't get back to it till now. *Pose* is more like the verb for the actions, right? *Pose for a shot.* We can talk about candid photos as if it were almost a kind of genre. *Candid photos look quite natural*. *Staged* might work, but something like *I like staged photos* sounds awkward, maybe we would opt for something more specific like *group* photos (which are generally not candid).

Answer (score 2):

The central idea conveyed by the word *candid* in the phrase "candid photo" is that the photo captures a spontaneous, unrehearsed, and unscripted moment: The tableau "just happened."

That being the case, perhaps "structured photo" or "scripted photo" or "rehearsed photo" or "staged photo" would convey the desired sense of nonspontaneity that makes for the opposite of a "candid photo." Of these options, I think that "staged photo" comes closest to conveying idiomatically the sense of artifice that went into the planning of the photo.

But to my mind "posed photo" may still come closest to being the true opposite of "candid photo"—especially if you think of the posing as being done by the photographer (in arranging the scene in a particular way, much as a theater or film director might structure a scene), rather than as being done by the subject of the picture (in striking a particular attitude).

Answer (score 2):

> Neither staged photo nor posed photo sounds right though.

Nonetheless, a photograph that is not posed (which was the norm for a long time, and once a necessity due to the longer exposure times) is *candid*, and hence vice-versa.

Hence the answer is *posed*.

*Staged* refers to a subset of posed photographs; those which attempt to appear candid, while they are not.

> Pose is more like the verb for the actions, right?

Yes, and hence the past participle *posed* can be used as an adjective to describe such photographs.

> We can talk about candid photos as if it were almost a kind of genre.

Not really. Any photograph of a person that is not posed would be called *candid*.

Now, that fact about the photograph gives it a certain value and hence when journalistic, artistic or pornographic shots are candid that difference can be particularly sought over to the extent of being demarcated as a genre in itself (the lines of genre are constructed, rather than innate), particularly in the case of pornography.

But having a genre built around a feature doesn't change the feature, and candid photographs that don't meet other criteria for such sub-genres (candid journalist shots and candid pornographic shots are not the same, despite the likes of the Daily Mail producing the latter and claiming it is the former) remain *candid*. All the more so, those which do not fit the description remain *posed* whether we consider *candid* as a genre or not.

Answer (score -2):

'Posed' is what comes to me first.